# Mapping an array to a JavaScript object to get an array of another field

Tags: javascript

```
const test_data = [
    {
        _id: '111',
        title: 'Book',
    },
    {
        _id: '222',
        title: 'Cat,
    }
]
```

I have data that looks like this, and I want to use an array of titles `e.g. ['Book', 'Cat']` to retrieve an array of the `_id`s that match with the title.

From that sample array, I want to retrieve `['111', '222']`.

What I've tried was

`test_data.filter((item) => { return item.title === "Book" })`

But it only retrieves a single object that has `Book` as the title.

How can I apply this using multiple string values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Set` for you look up table, if the value is present in the set filter the `data` and map it using the `_id`:

```js
const test_data = [
    {
        _id: '111',
        title: 'Book',
    },
    {
        _id: '222',
        title: 'Cat',
    }
];

const filterSet = new Set(["Book", "Cat"]);

console.log(test_data.filter(({title}) => filterSet.has(title))
                     .map( ({_id}) => _id));
```

Comment: Does this keep the order?

Comment: @Dawn17 yes `Array.prototype.filter` will keep the order, and same for map

Answer (score 0):

for titles:

```
test_data.map(entry => entry.title);
```

for ids:

```
test_data.map(entry => entry.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter and map

```js
const test_data = [{'_id': '111',title: 'Book',},{'_id': '222',title: 'Cat',}]
let conditions = ['Book', 'Cat']

let final = test_data
            .filter(({ title }) => conditions.includes(title))
            .map(({ _id }) => _id)

console.log(final)
```

Comment: Would this actually keep the order too `e.g. Book matching with 111`?

Comment: @Dawn17 order will depends on your test_data as we are looping on test_data to filter values

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use an array of titles e.g. ['Book', 'Cat'] to retrieve an
>   array of the _ids that match with the title.

If you mean to retrieve id using the title, then the following may help you.

```
const test_data = [
  {
      _id: '111',
      title: 'Book',
  },
  {
      _id: '222',
      title: 'Cat',
  }
]

let new_test_data={};
for(let obj of test_data)
{
  new_test_data[obj.title]=obj._id
}

console.log(new_test_data);//{ Book: '111', Cat: '222' }
console.log(new_test_data["Book"]); //111
console.log(new_test_data["Cat"]); //111
```